# How to increase the scrolling speed in Google Chrome without using a plugin on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, scrolling

I am using **Google Chrome** on Ubuntu but Ubuntu does not provide any setting for setting the scrolling speed. I know there is a plugin for solving this, `Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller`. However, its performance seems not as good as a native scrolling. Can I set the scrolling speed in another way?

Comment: Its a good question, would like to know an answer too, even its an old question. Have still not found a solution. My current approach is a plugin for that but it changes css of websites so it sucks for web development.